# Connecting to the network

Tags: android

I'm starting with android, my question is regarding to this official tutorial:

> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

In the "Perform network operations on a Separate Thread", I have the exact same code in eclipse and I get the following error in eclipse:

```
The type MainActivity.DownloadWebpageText must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask.doInBackground(Object...)
```

I understand that to override `doInBackground()` it must get an object as parameter and I expecting and String...

How do i solve that?

I'm pretty confused, because this code is in the main android training section.

Thank you very much and merry christmas!

EDIT: Here's my code. Same code that the guide i linked:

```
package com.example.com.example.networkoperations;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    final String LOG_TAG = "Connectivity tests (chux)";

    Button btn;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        tvText("Clicado!");
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            new DownloadWebpageText().execute("http://mydomain.com");
        }
        else
            tvText("No hay conexión a internet");
    }


    private void tvText(String text){
        String oldText = tv.getText().toString() + "\n";
        tv.setText(oldText + text);

    }

    private class DownloadWebpageText extends AsyncTask{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tv.setText(result);
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried :)

Comment: it works, but i'm a bit lost.. i don't know why the official code don't work. The Husam response works fine... but i'm lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the you class deceleration of downloading from

```
 private class DownloadWebpageText extends AsyncTask{
}
```

to be like

```
    private class DownloadWebpageText extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
}
```

Comment: What is the reason in the guide they don't put the <String, Void, String>? and what does that mean? i come from web page development and php, i haven't used something like that

Comment: Ok, those are generic types http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html where its provide an overview about AsyncTask class and its usage, and its means that<String,Void,String> the first string the one that you want to process in doInBackground() method, while Void if you want to use like processing Dialog you place instead Integer but in your case use Void, and the Last String for the result that you expected from doInBackground() method